The Speedtest is functioning properly on the development server, but it is not working on the live server. Why might this be the case?
https://account.speedtestcustom.com/login
I want it to work smoothly on both the local and live servers. Currently, it only loads content in an iframe on the development server, but it's not functioning on the live and local servers.
<Dialog
        fullScreen={fullScreen}
        open={open}
        onClose={onClose}
        aria-labelledby="dialog-title"
        fullWidth
        maxWidth="xl">
        <DialogContent className={classes.content}>
          <iframe
            onLoad={() => {
              this.setState({ loaded: true });
            }}
            title="Speed Test"
            frameBorder="0"
            src="here custom url"
          />
          {loaded ? null : (
            <div className={classes.spinner}>
              <CircularProgress />
            </div>
          )}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={onClose} color="primary">
            ok
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>

